# ViewController.h and ViewController.m Prefix

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Okay so I have just started programming in Xcode 4.3. All of the books I use to practice coding in Xcode the Examples show the ViewController.h and ViewController.m take the name of the project name as their prefixes. For instance... If the book named the application "Calculator" , in the examples the View Controllers are both named "CalculatorViewController.h" & "CalculatorViewController.m". Am I doing something wrong here??
I apologize if this is a newbie question, but Ive tried doing almost everything to figure this out!

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

When you add files into your project (class .h and .m files) there is not an automatic mechanism that prefixes these files for you, based on your product's name. You have to do it manually.

The reason you see that pattern in the books is because is a common practice to prefix your files with some initials so to [namespace](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php#2) them and avoid conflicts when working with someone else's code (that's why Apple's classes are prefixed with an 'NS').

Xcode 4 even lets you choose that prefix when you create a new project, so if you type in your application name there (for example 'Calculator') the files that will be created initially for you by Xcode will be prefixed accordingly (so you'll get a `CalculatorViewController` for example), but for any other files that you add, you have to explicitly prefix them as you like. I hope that this makes sense.

---

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Comment: Well I think you might have misunderstood the question. So ill name the "Calculator" but when Xode bring up the files, the view controllers are still just named "ViewController". Shouldn't it say "CalculatorViewController" ??? Ive even manually named the ViewControllers "CalculatorViewController.h" and the ".m" but when I implement or call it, Xcode will error me saying "CalculatorViewController" isn't recognized, or its an in correct implementation.

Comment: Well I think you might have misunderstood the answer then. I have included a screenshot to clarify a little bit more. Regarding the renaming of the controller: If you rename a file then the only thing really change in your code is the `#import` statement. The actual name of the class is still unchanged in the `@interface` and `@implementation` sections.